# Null checking before Update DML

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, null

Just a simple question for before update trigger:

```
// mapFinancialIDtoAccount and mapBillingAccounts being populated here.

for(CustomObject obj : trigger.new)
{
   Account billingAcct = mapFinancialIDtoAccount.get(obj.financialAccountID);

   if (billingAcct != null)
        obj.BillingAccountID = string.valueof(billingAcct.Id);

   if(obj.BillingAccountID != null) 
   {
        Account acct = mapBillingAccounts.get(record.BillingAccountID);
        obj.Name = acct.Name;
   }
}
update trigger.new;
```

Let's say billingAcct is not null but the update DML is after the for loop, will **obj.BillingAccountID** have value on **if(obj.BillingAccountID != null)** even though I've just populated it above? Or do I have to update it twice (one on population of **obj.BillingAccountID** and the other one to update the whole record in trigger.new)?

Comment: Which trigger event are you using, is it Before or After? In Before trigger you do not need to provide additional update statement on trigger.new. In After Trigger the records are Read Only so DML on trigger.new will throw error.

Comment: @Sneh I am using before trigger. So does it mean it will have value even though the update dml is in the last part of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will have the value. You do not need to have update statement for trigger.new in before triggers. The value will automatically update in the records.

You can validate the values using System.debug

```
obj.BillingAccountID = string.valueof(billingAcct.Id);
System.debug('BillingAccountID ' + obj.BillingAccountID);
```